# What would be an appropriate translation of the expression "strike the iron while it's hot"?

Tags: translation, expression

What would be an appropriate translation of the expression "strike the iron while it's hot" in German?

Comment: Interestingly the french expression *"Battons le fer quand il est chaud"* from ["L'Internationale"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Internationale) is not translated in the most popular German version (*"duldet die Schmach nun länger nicht!"*)

Comment: -1 `strike while the iron is hot` wird aufgeführt, wenn man bei Leo nach "strike" sucht. "Schmieden Eisen heiß" - die Schlüsselwörter, wörtlich übersetzt, liefern bei Google sofort das Sprichwort, mit [wiktionary Eintrag.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Man_muss_das_Eisen_schmieden,_solange_es_hei%C3%9F_ist). This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikiproverbs](http://www.wikiproverbs.com/index.php/Mann_soll_das_Eisen_schmieden,_solange_es_heiss_ist.) suggest three different versions.

- *Das Eisen schmieden, solange es heiss ist.*
  Translation: "Forge the iron while it's still hot."
  Google hits: 62.800
- *Heu machen, wenn die Sonne scheint.*
  Translation: "Make the hay when the sun is still up."
  Google hits: 41
- "Pflück die Rose, wenn sie blüht, Schmiede, wenn das Eisen glüht."
  Translation: "Pick flowers when they blossom; forge, when the iron glows.
  Google hits: 48

So the first variant is by far the most common.

*Note that the Google frequency is heavily influenced by the exact wording used, so the real numbers are somewhat higher. I could for example also count the hits for "Mach heu, wenn die Sonne scheint"*.

Comment: + "Iss die Suppe, bevor sie kalt wird" und scherzhaft "Trink das Bier, bevor es kalt wird".

Answer (score 11):

["Man muss das Eisen schmieden, solange es heiß ist."](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/man_muss_das_Eisen_schmieden,_solange_es_hei%C3%9F_ist)

It is a rather common proverb.

Answer (score 1):

"Das Eisen schmieden, solange es heiß ist" is certainly a good translation, but - in Austria at least - there's also the more colloquial "Nur nichts anbrennen lassen", lit. "Don't let anything get burned", referring to food. It means not to let a chance pass you by.